# Core Data - initWithEntity causes unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I want to use core data to persist some entities like events.

Therefore I use the classes `DSManagedObject` and `Event`

The class `DSManagedObject` extends `NSManagedObject` and has general methods that all entities can use.
The class `Event` extends `DSManagedObject`.

The following code is the `DSManagedObject.h` and `.m`. The relevant code in the `.m` is just the `getContext`-method.

```
@interface DSManagedObject : NSManagedObject

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContext;
- (NSArray*)getEntitiesForName:(NSString*)_entityName context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)_context;
- (Event*)getEntityForName:(NSString*)_entityName forEventId:(NSInteger)_eventId context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)_context;
- (bool)deleteEntityForName:(NSString*)_entityName forEventId:(NSInteger)_eventId context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)_context;

@end


@implementation DSManagedObject

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContext {

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingFormat:@"DesertStorm.sqlite"]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error loading persistent store..");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeUrl.path error:nil];
        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }



    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

    return context;


}
```

Now in the class `Event` I want to call `initWithEntity` but then the error `[Event managedObjectModel] unrecognized selector sent to instance` occurs.
What's the reason ? :(

```
@interface Event : DSManagedObject

@property (assign)              NSInteger   eventId;

@end


@implementation Event

@dynamic eventId;

- (id)init {

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[DSManagedObject getContext]];
    self = [self initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[DSManagedObject getContext]];  // error occurs
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

...

@end
```

I'm new in using core data so show understanding ;)
Thanks for help

PS: If you wonder why I override the `init`-method...complex reason^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in the `init`-method.
I still override the method (I know I shouldnt but...anyway)

Here's the code

```
- (id)init {
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[DSManagedObject getContext]];
}
```

this will return a NSManagedObject and no errors occur :)

Answer (score 5):

From [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html) doc:

> In a typical Cocoa class, you usually override the designated
>   initializer (often the init method). In a subclass of NSManagedObject,
>   there are three different ways you can customize initialization —by
>   overriding initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:,
>   awakeFromInsert, or awakeFromFetch. **You should not override init.** You
>   are discouraged from overriding
>   initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: as state changes made
>   in this method may not be properly integrated with undo and redo. The
>   two other methods, awakeFromInsert and awakeFromFetch, allow you to
>   differentiate between two different situations:

So the soultions are to override initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: or take advantage of `awakeFromInsert` or `awakeFromFecth`. If you want, ovveride the former since is called after
you invoke `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` or `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.

Is there a particular goal that you want to achieve?

**edit**

Try to override `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` instead of `init`

```
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription*)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context    
{    
    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self != nil) {

        // Perform additional initialization.

    }

    return self;    
}
```

**The method is the designated initializer for NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by sending it init.** See [`NSManagedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:) class for further info.

Comment: It takes me to the goal ;) Do you know why the error 'CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Event' ' occurs when I dont call 'initWithEntity'? Is it a must to call 'initWithEntity'?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me in understanding core data a bit more. I solved the problem (see my answer)

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar You're welcome! If possible mark yur answer as answered. Cheers.